# Passing a URL through the entry widget (TKinter // Python 3+)

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, dropbox, pytube

I have been trying to put together a few lines of code that takes a youtube music video URL and converts it to mp3/mp4 + 720p, and then downloads it to my DropBox music folder.

When I'm trying to pass a URL through a TKinter widget (entry bar) I am hitting an error about how the the entry object has no attribute 'type', or that the URL is invalid. Is it something to do with not adding quotation marks to the youtube link or something?

If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it. I assume I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import tkinter
from pytube import *
from tkinter import *

top=tkinter.Tk()
yt_variable = StringVar()

def helloCallBack():
    #Select youtube link you want to upload and print contents
    yt = YouTube(yt_entry)
    print(yt.get_videos())
    print(yt.filename)    
    #Set parameters for youtube video
    video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')
    print(yt.videos)
    print("success")

    #Select download location for youtube video
    video.download('C:/Users/coope/Dropbox/BrokenBow/Music/')
    print("Downloaded " + str(yt.filename) + " to " + str(video.download) + " successfully!")
    return

yt_label=tkinter.Label(top,text='Paste Link + Press Go')
yt_label.pack()
yt_button=tkinter.Button(top,text='Go',command= helloCallBack)
yt_button.pack()
yt_entry=tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=yt_variable)
yt_entry.get()
yt_entry.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the entire traceback.

Comment: Aside: Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to concatenate strings instead of using `+`.

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytube\api.py", line 158, in from_url
    video_data = self.get_video_data()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytube\api.py", line 254, in get_video_data
    response = urlopen(self.url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 456, in open
    protocol = req.type
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: ok will do, thank you for the tip @BhargavRao

Comment: Please don't paste code or stacktraces in the comment section; they are impossible to read. You can edit your question by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41319236/edit) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, you have the following:

```
yt_entry=tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=yt_variable)
yt_entry.get()
yt = YouTube(yt_entry)
```

You are expecting this to create an `Entry` widget, retrieve its contents, and send that retrieved value to the `YouTube()` constructor. It does not work like that. You are actually creating an `Entry` widget, *immediately* retrieving its contents, throwing away those contents (which will be empty anyway, since by that point you haven't had a chance to put anything into that field), and then attempting to send the `Entry` widget itself to the `YouTube()` constructor.

On top of that, you give the `Entry` widget a `textvariable`, but then you never use it.

Instead, retrieve the contents of that `Entry` widget (via its `textvariable`) within the callback. You can even do it in the `YouTube()` constructor call.

```
...
top=tkinter.Tk()
yt_variable = StringVar()

def helloCallBack():
    ...
    yt = YouTube(yt_variable.get())
    ...

...
yt_entry=tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=yt_variable)
yt_entry.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Since you're not doing anything special with that `Entry` widget, there's no need for a `textvariable` at all.

```
...
top=tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
    ...
    yt = YouTube(yt_entry.get())
    ...

...
yt_entry=tkinter.Entry(top,)
yt_entry.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Also, there's no need for a bare `return` at the end of a function. It will return regardless once there's nothing more to do, with a default return value of `None` (the same as what gets returned with a bare `return` statement, or with `return None`).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that, now I understand what I was doing (and I feel really embarrassed for not realizing I was just calling the widget itself).